# Avoid repeating same shared members of different classes

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, shared

Consider the following two classes:

```
Class A
    Shared Property P1 As Integer = 1
    Shared Property P2 As Integer = 5
    '
    '
    '
    Shared Property P20 As Integer = 123

    Shared Property A1 As Integer
End Class
```

---

```
Class B
    Shared Property P1 As Integer = 2
    Shared Property P2 As Integer = 7
    '
    '
    '
    Shared Property P20 As Integer = 456

    Shared Property B1 As Integer
End Class
```

Clearly, `P1` to `P20` are repeated in multiple classes but they have different values. For non-shared members, to avoid this, we'd normally create a base class with all the common members, and then derive that class.

So, is there a similar way to avoid this repetition with shared members?

---

### Edit:

Okay, what I'm actually trying to do is the following:
I have multiple excel sheets that share some columns, (columns order is not the same), in addition to other columns. And I have a method that does some manipulation to the sheet, so I started by doing this:

```
UpdateSheet(productsDT, filePath, New Integer() {1, 8, 9, 16, 17, 29, 30})

Private Sub UpdateSheet(productsDT As DataTable, sheetPath As String, columnIndices As Integer())
    Dim codeColIndex As Integer = columnIndices(0)
    Dim stockColIndex As Integer = columnIndices(1)
    Dim newStockColIndex As Integer = columnIndices(2)
    Dim priceColIndex As Integer = columnIndices(3)
    Dim newPriceColIndex As Integer = columnIndices(4)
    Dim newItemColIndex As Integer = columnIndices(5)
    Dim removedItemColIndex As Integer = columnIndices(6)

    'Excel work
    '
    '
    xlSheet.Cells(rowIndex, codeColIndex) = '....
End Sub
```

But the problem with this method (using an array) is that the number of the shared columns might become bigger, and also I wanted to access the indices of the other columns as well, so I decided to change the `UpdateSheet` method to be something like the following:

```
Private Sub UpdateSheet(productsDT As DataTable, sheetPath As String, columnIndices As MyIndicesClass)
    Dim codeColIndex As Integer = MyIndicesClass.Code
    '
    '
End Sub
```

Or use an enum variable instead of the `columnIndices` argument to determine the type of the passed sheet.

Hope that makes better sense, and I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Why do you have so many shared members anyway?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I'm trying to represent indices of members that belong to multiple items. If you're interested, [this](https://s28.postimg.org/68bmvuad9/del.png) was my original question but I thought it might be confusing so I deleted it and wrote this simplified version.

Comment: I think it would be useful to know exactly what you want to accomplish with these classes in real code. for example roughly what the various classes represent and what all the members are for. There may be a completely different approach available

Comment: @DavidWilson, I totally agree, and I'm actually open to suggestions of different approaches. Could you please check the link in my previous comment? Or should I edit the question (or even undelete the other one)?

Comment: Yes - I saw that question, and that didn't explain why you need this either. Is it for some kind of stock system, or retail? What do you need this code for?

Comment: I agree this is too abstract, but you might be able to use instance readonly properties in place of all those SHARED members.  Use an enum to specify what type of thing is being created and let the class set the RO props based on that in the ctor

Comment: @DavidWilson, I just edited the question. Please take a look.

Comment: Hmm. Let me think about it. Gotta disappear for now - back later. Sorry

Comment: @Plutonix, You mean something like the code [here](https://s28.postimg.org/68bmvuad9/del.png)? Edit: That was the original question and I deleted it and wrote this one.

Comment: Not really, but that seems closer to something that would be useful.  Since the indices are dependent on something else they ought to be RO and fixed, but what type you initialize it to can be set when you create it

Comment: @Plutonix, if I go with this approach, I can make them RO yes, but I don't get what you mean by *"what type you initialize it to can be set when you create it"*

Comment: `Class A` is one Type, `Class B` is another Type.  Create an Enum of all the different Types and pass the desired one via the ctor.

Comment: @Plutonix, Sorry, I'm still confused. You mean I should end up with one or more classes? If I'll end up with multiple classes and their members are not `Shared`, what would I need the Enum for? I could use inheritance. And if I'll end up with one class that I pass an enum to its ctor to initialize the properties with the corresponding values, I don't see how this fits my case (considering that the different types *also* have other members that are not common).

Comment: The common properties could either be in a base class, then each inherited Type (CLASS) calls `MyBase(enumType)` to do the column mapping, **or** the mapping could be a private helper class each main type (Class) creates.  Which one is the best fit depends on how many there are and how they are used.

Comment: How about you have one class, but the indices names and values are a key/value pair in a dictionary/hashtable stored in the class, and when you instantiate the class, you pass the column names and values to the ctor?

Comment: And then use `For..Next Step2` to add the items to a the dictionary.

Comment: @DavidWilson, good suggestion. Will give it a try. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Factory Pattern to create updater classes. The classes would have a common base class. Each derived class will set the column indices in their constructors. As mentioned in comments, an Enum can be used to tell the factory which class to instantiate.

Base Class

```
MustInherit Class SheetUpdaterBase
    Protected Property CodeColIndex As Integer
    Protected Property StockColIndex As Integer
    Public Sub UpdateSheet(productsDT As DataTable, sheetPath As String)
        ' Excel work
    End Sub
End Class
```

Derived Classes

```
Class UpdaterClass1
    Inherits SheetUpdaterBase
    Public Sub New()
        CodeColIndex = 1
        StockColIndex = 2
    End Sub
End Class

Class UpdaterClass2
    Inherits SheetUpdaterBase
    Public Sub New()
        CodeColIndex = 1
        StockColIndex = 5
    End Sub
End Class
```

Enum

```
Enum UpdaterClassEnum
    UpdaterClass1
    UpdaterClass2
End Enum
```

Class Creator (Factory)

```
Module Factory
    Public Function CreateUpdater(updaterClass As UpdaterClassEnum) As SheetUpdaterBase
        Select Case updaterClass
            Case UpdaterClassEnum.UpdaterClass1
                Return New UpdaterClass1()
            Case UpdaterClassEnum.UpdaterClass2
                Return New UpdaterClass2()
            Case Else
                Return Nothing
        End Select
    End Function
End Module
```

Usage

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim myUpdater1 = Factory.CreateUpdater(UpdaterClassEnum.UpdaterClass1)
        myUpdater1.UpdateSheet(New DataTable(), "path1")
        Dim myUpdater2 = Factory.CreateUpdater(UpdaterClassEnum.UpdaterClass1)
        myUpdater2.UpdateSheet(New DataTable(), "path2")
    End Sub
End Module
```

See the entry on Wikipedia for [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#VB.NET); it is basically the same as this code, except it uses an Interface. I chose an abstract class in order to define `UpdateSheet` in which common code can be defined once the column indices are set in the constructor.

Comment: This is similar to what I first thought of. My idea was to pass the instance of the class to the updater method, however your suggestion to have the method inside the base class is more elegant. Thank you so much! +1

Comment: Oh, actually I won't be able to add the updating method in the base class because it needs to access other column indices which are not shared between the types.

Comment: You can "have" it there, as a virtual method. But you have the freedom to have or not have common code in a method when using an abstract class. If you don't want to share any implementation, you can still use an interface. I suspect though that you should be able to have some concrete code in common...